# Running a Cronjob on 1&1 Shared Hosting [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I have created a scheduled task, as defined in a [previous question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173911/running-a-cronjob-with-laravel-5-6-using-the-scheduler/51174053#51174053). It essentially grabs data and updates a few tables.

I followed a help article on 1&1 about [creating cronjobs](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/cron-jobs-c37727/create-a-cron-job-a595882.html).

To summarise this article it said the following.

> SSH to your server, that you want to set up the new cronjob on, use **whereis php** to find the location of your PHP Binary, then use the **crontab** command to access the crontab and add a new job.
>
> This will require the PHP path and the path to the script that is to be run.

The issue is when I run that command I get the following.

> No crontab for [username]

So, I then Googled and it seems some shared hosts don't allow you to use or even access the crontab.

On my shared hosting server the path to **php-7.1-cli** is as follows `/usr/bin/php7.1-cli`

Now, Artisan is part of Laravel and requires a higher version of PHP than what is found in **\usr\bin\php**

Given this, for the cronjob I thought I'd be able to do something like this:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1-cli /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Or

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1-cli /path/to/mynewable/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

My folder structure is as follows:

```
root
    /mynewable
```

But when I run either of these commands, nothing happens.

1&1 also has an inbuilt cron job creator but this only allows me to specify a URL path to a file that would run the necessary script.

[image]

Am I being prevented from using crontab? If so, giving a URL seems impractical as the user wouldn't need to validate, but making a path in web routes to run the Laravel scheduler seems a bit of a security hole.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? /var/log/cron, /var/log/messages and/or /var/log/syslog.

Comment: URL-based cron has limitations - I'd bet 1&1's hosting is configured so HTTP calls timeout fairly quickly. Your cron may wind up timing out if it's doing any hefty processing. I'd be looking for a better host.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a executable `cron.php` in your public folder of laravel.

```
exec("/usr/bin/php7.2-cli -f /homepages/x/xxxxx/htdocs/artisan schedule:run 2>&1", $out, $result);

if(!empty($out)) {
    echo implode("<br>\n\n", $out);
}
```

Now you can call http://example.org/cron.php

Of course you can put the `cron.php` in a protected directory so no one can call the `cron.php`.

Comment: Laravel has a built-in scheduler, so it's entirely unnecessary to make a separate `cron.php` - you just put in `php artisan schedule:run` as the command directly in crontab.

Comment: You can’t run crontab at 1und1 because it’s a shared webhoster. You can only call URLs. No Shell Commands.

Comment: You'd still be better off doing it all in Laravel. A route that does `Artisan::call('schedule:run')` would still let you use the scheduler properly.